# Azure maps indoor module : How to draw a path between two points in indoor navigation using azure maps?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-maps

I am working on POC for Azure maps indoor navigation using WEB SDK. For this, I have followed all the documentation (Using creator upload sample_drawing_package.zip, you can check this link for doc: [Use Creator to create indoor maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-creator-indoor-maps).

**Requirement:** I want to to draw a path in between two points (these points configured as datasets/tiles/units in indoor map).

**For more Info, please check this GitHub query  conversation : [Get Navigable Lat and Long between two Units](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59829)

I request someone help me on this.

Comment: Microsoft team is also looking into this[Github], Please share your additional comments if you have on this request...

Comment: Thanks for your response @SatishBoddu-MSFT. And the path which we have shown in the screenshot  (as given in this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59829) is displaying in all levels (Basement -0,Floor-1,Floor-2). If I want to show the path only in Basement, but not in Floor-1 & Floor-2 ,How can I achieve this too ?

Comment: As an initial response, I am following up on the Github, we first thought of a Feature request, but please stay tuned for further updates on these two platforms.

Comment: Could you please accept the below response from PG team so that it is helpful to others as well.Please stay tuned on Azure Maps Indoor [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-indoor-module) or Subscribe to [Azure updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?category=iot&query=Azure%20Maps) for all quick updates related to Azure Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indoor routing is not yet supported, but is planned.